# Wrap inline function with generic type into a non-inline function

Tags: kotlin, generics

one of the library privides an inline functionA. Since inline function cannot be mocked for unit testing, I'm trying to wrap it into a non-inline function but not sure how to pass the clazz to functionA.
Please help.

```
inline fun <reified T> functionA(string: String): T {
  // some implementation

}
```

```
fun <T> functionAWrap(string:String, clazz:Class<T>):T {
  return functionA<???>(string)  // not sure how to implement here
}
```

In my project, I would expect to call

```
functionAWrap(testString, AClass::class.java)
```

instead of

```
functionA<AClass>(testString)
```

Comment: It is not possible to do this in a generalized way. You have to write a wrapper function for each specific type you might test.

Comment: FYI, I added an answer to the duplicate that shows it's possible if you can modify the source of the Kotlin class. For your case specifically, you have to call the non-inline function *from* the inline one, instead of the other way around.